# Intersection of sets from info on unions and unique count of elements in both sets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am having difficulty understanding sets and specifically if it is feasible to determine the intersection of sets from this limited information. I cannot seem to!

Suppose the following example of two groups of individuals:

- Set A contains 3,000 individuals who bought oranges
- Set B contains 1,600 individuals who bought apples
- There were 4,000 individuals who bought oranges or apples

It is understood that some individuals have bought both oranges and apples. Can it be estimated how many from the data above?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Hint: $3000+1600=4600>4000$. Apparantly some folks are doubly counted. What folks?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following argument, using simultaneous equations, may help. There are three kinds of people in your question:

1) Those who buy only oranges, call the number of these as $x$.

2)Those who buy only apples, call the number of these as $y$.

3)Those who buy both, call the number of these as $z$.

We would like the value of $z$.

From the information we are given, the following is true:

For those who bought either, the information gives $x+y+z = 4000$ (those who bought either one or both)

For set $A$, the information gives $x+z = 3000$ (those who bought oranges)

For set $B$, the information gives $y+z = 1600$ (those who bought only apples)

Now, solve these equations: we get $y=1000$ from the first and second equations, hence we get $z=600$ from the third equation.

Hence, $600$ people bought both. I hope you have understood.

Now, as it turns out, there is no need to do all this. You have this wonderful set equivalence:
$$
|(A \cup B)| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| 
$$
Where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets. Can you see why this happens? Reason out using the sets $A$ and $B$ above, and use the definition of $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ to get the  answer in a second way.

Now, the approach of simultaneous equations is capable of telling you whether you have enough information to exactly discern the value you are looking for. In this case, the equations were solvable, but they may not be in another case, so that is always  the safer approach to this kind of a question as a beginner.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It makes perfect sense!

Comment: @user2716667 You are welcome!